# Sixties short story with a typewriter and an alien uses a young boy's body to find an escaped criminal?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find a sixties short story of a young boy sitting at a typewriter and a host begins to type that he has to use the boy's body to find an escaped criminal from another planet.  I keep thinking the name was Host.  At the end the host cannot return to his planet and the boy invites him to coexist.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133315/title-of-a-book-about-a-young-boy-who-merges-with-an-alien-amoeba (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

I would guess "Needle" by Hal Clement due to high similarity of plot structure, but (if I recall correctly) initial contact with the boy is via forming letters on his retina from inside his eyes (not via typewriter). See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needle_%28novel%29

Comment: A typewriter does feature in Needle, but the Hunter does not use it. The boy is away at boarding school and the  typewriter is a gift from his parents, perhaps as "a gentle hint" to write more often.

Comment: Actually The Hunter (the alien) tries to get teh boy's fingers to type out a message, but can't get enough leverage. It is aftert that the Hunter tries words in the boy's field of vision