# Book about a man with an alien cop that lived inside him, healed him when needed and chased a fugitive

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for a book about an alien that lives inside a man.  It heals him when need be.  Takes place on a Pacific island.  It is a sequel to a book of when the alien crashed on this planet.  The alien is a cop chasing a fugitive.

This would be an old book.

Comment: Don't have a title (yet), but the little screen in my head is flashing "Hal Clement."

Comment: I don't recall the bit about a sequel, but very likely _Needle_ by Hal Clement? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133315/title-of-a-book-about-a-young-boy-who-merges-with-an-alien-amoeba

Comment: Thats it.  I had Hal, but not the last name.  And I thought it was eye of the needle, not just Needle.  Thanks folks!!!!!

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1875502.Through_the_Eye_of_a_Needle

Comment: Not strictly a dupe IMO since this is about the sequel.

Comment: Even though you've found it, could you add some details, for the benefit of other users? When did you read it? What did it look like? You can [edit] our question to add any other details.

Answer (score 11):

This is Hal Clement's *[Through the Eye of a Needle](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1875502.Through_the_Eye_of_a_Needle)* (1979).
Thank you everyone, I knew you would be able to help.

From a Goodreads review:

> This sequel novel to Needle, was written and published in 1978, some 29 years after its predecessor but takes place only a few years later. The main character, Bob Kinnaird has completed his college degree and returned to his Polynesian island home to confront and get help for what has become all too obvious: his alien symbiont and friend (the Hunter) has lingered too long in his host body and is leading to the complete deterioration and breakdown of Bob’s body. What follows is a concerted effort by Bob and his friends to contact the aliens to obtain some form of cure or reversal of this process.