Book about two aliens inside two humans
I'm looking for a sci-fi book (probably from the '60s or '70s) that describes the story of two aliens that have landed on earth. I only remember a few things of the story:

It is told from the viewpoint of one of the two men who has an alien inside him - he discovers it as the alien manipulates his muscles while he uses a typewriter, and so makes this presence known to the man. He then tries to find the fiend of the alien, which is inside some other man.
The alien can wander inside the body of the man, and later they communicate not via the typewriter, but through the alien manipulating directly the brain (or ears?) of the human.
The second man, being the host to the second alien, once throws a sawblade like a frisbee. This is observed by the first man, and he later realizes that it can only be that this does not cause wounds because this man is the host of the second alien (who protects the skin from the inside).


You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

I've closed your question as a duplicate. This is not a censure, but a bookkeeping measure. :) You will still get points for upvotes.

Needle by Hal Clement.  The good alien "Hunter" is inside a boy named Robert Kinnard, and they seek the bad alien "Killer" who is in an unknown person. The sawblade incident is a clue to the identity of the person within whom Killer hides.
From the wikipage:

The Hunter, an alien lifeform (when not inside another being,
resembling a four-pound green jellyfish) with the ability to live in
symbiosis with and within another creature, is in hot pursuit of
another of his kind. Both crash their ships into Earth, in the Pacific
Ocean, and both survive the crashes.
The Hunter makes its way to shore (its erstwhile host having been
killed in the crash) and takes up residence in the nearest human being
it can find (as it turns out, fifteen-year-old Robert Kinnaird)
without letting the human being know.

....

 The Hunter is able to solve the riddle by observing the behavior of the island people. Bob's father, known for his attention to detail and safety, has been taking amazing risks. He is at least unconsciously aware that an accident will have no ill consequences. The quarry resides within him. The Hunter confirms this, and Bob and the alien have a new puzzle—how to get the alien out of Mr. Kinnaird's body without harming the man?


Damn.  Gotta post before I go looking for supporting quotes.

Sorry about that. You'll beat me next time.

If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133315/title-of-a-book-about-a-young-boy-who-merges-with-an-alien-amoeba/133317#133317

Thanks, that was quick! You are geniuses!
Now I just have to find the book somewhere...

No problem Edith. It's a famous book and available in a lot of places (Interlibrary loan if nothing else).  Come back with more questions, and click the checkmark please.
